# CORS error With Laravel and Angular (new)

Tags: angular, laravel

I haven an Angular applicatin with Laravel backend and I got cors error, when i use dd function to debug.

What is the solution for this problem?

Comment: I faced the same issue when using dd() with react. My solution was to use Postman or use Log

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable CORS(Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) in your Laravel backend.